# How to rank transactions in custom order in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have some transactions in database. I need to rank the transaction in a custom order. The transactions are

[image]

Transactions needs to be given rank in descending order of csave column and transactions with same tx number will get the same rank. So i execute below query:

```
SELECT * , DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY csave desc, tx) AS rank
FROM noma_d.setu_test.report_result
```

**And the result:**

[image]

In the above transactions, for same tx, the value of csave column is same. Let's consider below transactions where for **tx =1**, **csave** values are different.

[image]

Now if i execute the same above query, then the result i got:

[image]

Here, one transaction of **tx = 1** has **rank = 2** and another transaction of **tx = 1** has **rank = 5**. But i want to give all the transactions of **tx = 1** to **rank = 2** as one transaction of the **tx = 1** got rank **2** so the rest of the transactions with **tx = 1** will also have to be given rank **2**.

**The expected output will be like below:**

[image]

***How will i achieve this by modifying my above query?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by JohnHC, need to group by the **tx** before ranking and also use **rank()** instead of **row_number()**. The final query is:

```
select t1.*, t2.rank
from noma_d.setu_test.report_result as t1
inner join 
(
    select a2.*, rank() over (order by csave desc, tx) as rank
    from 
    (
        select tx, max(csave) as csave
        from noma_d.setu_test.report_result
        group by tx
    ) a2
) t2
    on t1.tx = t2.tx
```

Comment: `rank` will give you the same value if you have `tx` with identical `max(csave)`, for your desired output (no repeated rank values for different `tx`) you have to use `row_number`

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the tx before ranking, so I've put this in a subquery:

```
select t1.*, t2.rank
from noma_d.setu_test.report_result
inner join 
(
    select a2.*, row_number() over (order by csave desc) as rank
    from 
    (
        select tx, max(csave) as csave
        from noma_d.setu_test.report_result
        group by tx
    ) a2
) t2
    on t1.tx = t2.tx
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @JohnHC. But if i execute your query, then rank for two different tx will be same. For the given transactions, rank of tx = 1 and tx = 4 will be 2. But they needs to be different. Expected output is that rank of tx = 1 will be 2 and rank of tx = 4 will be 3 or vice-versa. Means rank can't be equal for the same tx number though the value of csave column is same for them. you can see the output of your query here https://ibb.co/f5ajqF

Comment: replace `dense_rank` with `rank` or `row_number`. the former gives common rank for equal values

Comment: replacing dense_rank with rank won't do the needful for my expected output

Comment: @setubasak I mean replace in the query above, not in your original query, this is why I have put a comment here and not another response. Have you tried that?